# Calculate run time for leds

Tags: led, batteries

I have

- 8, 5 watt LEDs that run from a 12VDC source.
- 3, 18650 batteries at 3000mAh each.

I want to know the approx run time of the LEDs.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at and edit to your situation : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/210096/152903

Comment: Btw, 18650’s are nominally 3.7 V, so your battery pack will be nominally 11.1 V, not 12 V.

Answer (score 1):

Your load is 8*5=40W. Your source has 3A-h*12V = 36 W-h. In ideal case your LEDs will shine for 60*36/40 = 54 min = 0.9hr.

In reality, a 3,000 mAh battery has 3.7 * 3 *3 = 33W-h at best, since the average discharge voltage per Li-Ion cell is about 3.7V.

More, in best case the LEDs must be driven by switching type drivers, likely each drives two typical LEDS in series, and 4 chains. Switching-mode (the best!) will likely have 85-90% efficiency in 12:8 conversion mode, so overall your LEDs will run 60 * 33/40 *0.85 = 42 min.  If you have passive ballast resistors to drive the LEDs, it will be quite less than 40 min.

The above assumes that the LEDs are driven to truly 5W each.

Comment: Lights have run for 45 minutes. Battery voltage is now at 11.93 volts. Looks like it will run far more than 54 minutes.

Comment: @fixit7, then it looks like you run your lights at far less than 5W each. How do you know that it is 5 W?

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/10PCS-12v-Super-Bright-T10-5050-W5W-5SMD-Yellow-Wedge-Fog-158-168-194-LED-Bulbs/283422908666?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649

Comment: @fixit7, for this price, it looks like it is 5 x Yellow LEDs in-series with a ballast resistor, a very primitive design. And the 
"5W" is just a nameplate. This lamp will likely emit substantial light even at 10V consuming under 1W. No accurate estimations is possible without knowing actual input and light output of this automotive bulb.

Comment: Would checking current used with a multimeter help?

Comment: I think the bulbs are only 1 watt. Which would explain the long run time. https://www.amazon.com/JKLcom-Interior-Courtesy-License-Dashboard/dp/B074C474YV/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=12v+w5w+led&qid=1555960607&s=gateway&sr=8-4 ★Input: DC 12V
★Power: 1 W
★Life Span:50,000 hours

Comment: @fixit7, Would checking current used with a multimeter help? Yes, of course. Only make sure that the Ampermeter burden voltage is not too high, it will affect the state of LED. Better use a 0.1 Ohm 1% precision resistor in series, and measure the voltage drop across it.

Comment: 5050 SMD LED Specs
Number of Light Emitting Chips  3
Dimensions  50 x 50 mm
Power Consumption  0.24 watts per SMD

Comment: @fixit7, so, what is the actual power draw by your lamps?

Comment: Current used is 87 milliamps for one led.

Comment: @fixit7 "Current used is 87 milliamps for one led" - then 0.087 x 12V = 1W. Not 5W. Multiply my answer by 5 then. 33 W-h / 8W = ~ 4 hours.

Answer (score -1):

P = IV relates power, voltage and current, rearranged:

Led current = P/V = 5W/12A
0.4A/LED

Battery capacity of 9AH,

9AH/0.4A gives the time for one LED 
Divided by 8 = 22.5H/8

Should be about 2 hours and 45 minutes.

*Please* correct me if I am wrong, I need to know!

Comment: I would guess the cells are in series, so the capacity would only be 3 Ah.

Comment: @Callum I think Callum's calculation will be closer.

Comment: The mistake in the above calculations is that a battery of 3 cells in series will have the amper-hour capacity as one cell, 3 Ah.  Not 9 Ah.